# Callouts to self Salesforce Org no longer need named credentials

Tags: callout

Recently (In the last few months) I remember of reading in the Salesforce Release Notes (can not remember in which ones, though) that an enhancement was being introduced where, when you were using for example  **callout** to consume the **tooling API** or metadata API from apex, if you were doing it to your **same org** where the code was being executed, you did **no longer need a named credential** (this I am not sure either, it may was the session Id or something similar)

The thing is, I have tried to find this documentation again but with no luck. I have searched in the Sprint 21 and Winter 21 but did not find it there neither...

**Does someone remember to have seen something similar and where I can refer to it?**

Comment: Depending exactly the context of the callout, I would think that all you need is an appropriate session ID to include in the invocation... note that LWC invoked apex does not have such a session ID.

Comment: Yes.. I am painfully aware of that... May it be that, we no longer need to add our Self Salesforce URL to remote Site settings or named credential?

Comment: I am almost sure this is what I was lookin for: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_apex_streamline_api_calls.htm
thank you for your inputs though. It has take me few hours to figure it out